# Convertir video a mp4 con ffmpeg y php

Tags: php, php7, php5, ffmpeg

Necesito cambiar de formato un video y estoy tratando de usar `ffmpeg` en `php`, la verdad soy novel en este tema, buscando en internet encontré el siguiente código

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="video">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $currentPath=$_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
    exec("ffmpeg.exe"); 
    exec("ffmpeg -i ".$currentPath." -an ./output/video.mp4");

    echo "Ok";
}
?>
```

Este código si cambia el formato pero cuando se reproduce el vídeo no se escucha el audio, yo quise pensar que tal vez no esta convirtiendo con los codecs de audio y vídeo necesarios para el formato mp4,
se me ocurrió hacer el siguiente cambio:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$currentPath." -an ./output/video.mp4");
```

por

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$currentPath." -vcodec h264 -qscale:v 7 -vf 'scale=720:480' -acodec aac -b:a 128k -strict -2 ./output/video.mp4");
```

Pero no funciono, en la carpeta del proyecto tengo el ejecutable del `ffmpeg`, no tengo instalado ninguna librería ni nada.

Investigando y probando hice unos cambios en la invocación a la función exec y me esta funcionando:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$currentPath." -acodec aac -ab 128k -vcodec h264 -b 1200k video.mp4");
```

Ahora se que los `.exe` son archivos que solo se ejecutan en windows pero como podría hacer esto para linux?? Por que tengo entendido que los hosting tienen configurados sistemas linux(ubuntu, debian, suse, centos, etc).

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no tienes instalada ninguna librería? FFMpeg requiere que instales los códecs adecuados. Enlace antiguo que quizá todavía sea útil: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/conversion-videos-mp4-con-ffmpeg-desde-linux-suse-con-php-1132256/

Comment: @Triby investigando encontré que los archivos avcodec.dll y avformat.dll deben colocarse en windows/system32 y en php/ext debe colocarse el archivo php_ffmpeg.dll, de igual manera lo hice pero no funciono

Comment: Debes actualizar el comando, de acuerdo a las librerías instaladas. Por cierto, la librería php_ffmpeg hace siglos que dejaron de actualizarla, no es recomendable perder el tiempo con ella.